# how to cut after 20th element in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 taglists per site with unknown numbers of tags in it. I want to archive that after 20 tags the list gets cut and a link after the 20th tag gets appended which says "show more" and after clicking on it the rest of the tags will show.

This is my markup:

```
<div class="taglist example-one">
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
</div>
```

CSS not needed i suppose. if it's needed let me know.

My js i began with:

```
$(".taglist").each(function(){
    var tags = $(this).find(".tag");
    tags = tags.length;
    if(tags > 20) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You have some mistake in your code, you set `tags` as `tags.length` and then you do your condition with `tags.length` it should be `tags > 20`

Comment: you are right. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [greater than index](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) jQuery selector, insert a button and set relevant click handler. For example:

```js
$('.tag:gt(19)').hide();
$('<button/>', {text: "Show more..."}).on('click', function(){
   $('.tag:gt(19)').show();
   $(this).remove();
}).insertAfter('.tag:eq(20)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taglist example-one">
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
</div>
```

Comment: used the gt/eq-technique to get it to work but did it a little bit different. thank you anyway! i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.tag')).slice(0, 20);
```

This will return a normal javascript array with 20 first div elements which then you can do your stuff with.

Comment: Because people try to use jQuery for everything not knowing they have most of that stuff in plain javascript. Are you trying to accomplish the task or show you don't know the language? I'm not saying this to bash on people who use jQuery, but just learn the vanilla js and know what it can do first, then make your life easier with a library if you really need it.

Comment: jQuery is already within the project, so i won't do it the vanillaway :) but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can include CSS too. Please check below code snippet. Here I took count of 5. I have used lt (less than index), use can use gt (greater than index) either.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   div_size = $(".taglist div").size();
    x=5;
    $('.taglist div:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#showMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= div_size) ? x+5 : div_size;
        $('.taglist div:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<=0) ? 5 : x-5;
      
        $('.taglist div').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
  });
```

```css
.taglist div{ display:none;
}
#showMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#showMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taglist example-one">
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
 <div class="tag">Example</div>
</div>
<div id="showMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

Comment: `size()` is deprecated...use `length`